# Zod refine is not Working in multi nesting?

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, zod, next.js14

```
const transporterDetailsSchema =z.object({
  vehicleGuarantor:z.enum(['Self', 'Others']),
  ifOther:z.object({
    proofType: z.string().optional(),
   
  }),
  
 
    remarks:z.string(),
   
}).refine((data) => {
  if (data.vehicleGuarantor === 'Others' && (!data.ifOther.proofType)) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}, {
  message: "if you select Other Vehicle Guarantor , then it is required",
  path: ['ifOther', 'ifOther.proofType'],
});


const formSchema = z.object({
  
  transporterDetails : transporterDetailsSchema,
  adminId : z.string(),
});
```

Error set on refine is not working , If I select other in `transporterDetailsSchema` then ,I want `prooftype` in `ifOther` should be require else it will be optional.

before making this condition everything works well